# Tradingview alert with placeholder not working

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I created alert for simple moving average like {{plot("MA")}} {{time}}. Here {{time}} gets resolved but {{plot("MA")}} doesnt work. Any thoughts on what is missing?

SMA with alert message.
[image]

Alert settings
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *Condition* drop-down menu, you need to select the indicator that plots the MA. Otherwise, Tradingview cannot know what plot/script you are referring to.

[image]

Comment: Oh, fantastic, thanks! I spent quite some time puzzling over this.